# How to reset Interaction.Triggers in toggle button correctly with code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, data-binding

In my current C#/WPF project I use a toggle button with `Interaction.Triggers` to start and stop a measurement and it works as intended. You press the start button, it starts to measure, you press the stop button and it stops and resets the properties so you can do it again.

The process in the GUI [looks like this](https://gyazo.com/9209859294adaaed9460cd2a2dcecb0b):

XAML code:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ButtonMeasurementConnect" 
  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Content="{Binding ButtonDataAcquisitionName}"
  IsChecked="{Binding IsDataAcquisitionActivated, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartMeasurementCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StopMeasurementCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
```

Now I added the option to set a timer so the program automatically stops the measurement after a desired time [like in this example](https://gyazo.com/c9dda85136ec9d050706dd2479ad1614).

You can see that when I click the start button, the timer stops at 1 second, the start button name property resets correctly to "Start" again instead of "Stop".

Here's finally the problem: If I want to repeat it I have to press the "Start" button twice. First time pressing again will just result in invoking the S`topMeasurementCommand`.

How can I tell the toggle button that it should reset to using the `StartMeasurementCommand` binding the next time it gets used inside the code behind, not by pressing the button manually?

EDIT:
Here's the code inside the view model, first the obvious handling of the commands:

```
StartMeasurementCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnStartMeasurementExecute);
StopMeasurementCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnStopMeasurementExecute);
```

Here the `OnStopMeasurementExecute`:

```
try
{
    if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
    }
    _receivingDataLock = true;

    // Stop writing/consuming and displaying
    _sourceDisplay.Cancel();
    if (IsRecordingRequested)
    {
        _sourceWriter.Cancel();
    } else
    {
        _sourceConsumer.Cancel();
    }

    // Sending stop command to LCA
    _dataAcquisition.StopDataAcquisition();

    // Flags
    ButtonRecordingVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    IsDataAcquisitionActivated = false;
    IsDataAcquisitionDeactivated = true;
    ButtonDataAcquisitionName = "Start";

    if (IsRecordingRequested)
    {
        StatusMessage = "Recording stopped after " + CurrentTime;
    }
    else
    {
        StatusMessage = "Live data stopped after " + CurrentTime;
    }

    if (IsRecordingRequested) _recordedDataFile.Close();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in OnStopMeasurementExecute: " + e.Message);
    
}
```

If a timer is set it gets invoked by the timer function as well:

```
void Stopwatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (stopWatch.IsRunning)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        CurrentTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        if ((IsTimerActivated) && (MeasureTime>0)) {
            if (ts.Seconds >= MeasureTime) OnStopMeasurementExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. You want this button to act as a **Start** and **Stop** right? But you also want to act as **Start** only (not **Stop**) when is clicked repeatedly?

Comment: There is most probably an issue in your view model. Obviously the bound property `ButtonDataAcquisitionName` is reset to _Stop_ in your view model correctly, but `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` is not reset to `false`, resulting in the behavior you see. Without the code there is no way to point out the real issue.

Comment: In the second video you see that I checked the checkbox for the timer for 1 second. So the program will automatically stop the measurement after 1 second, there is no need to press the stop button again. So the button should return to his "Start" state but I don't know how I can do that with the code behind. @thatguy ... I check quickly, I might have been utterly blind to this property .. but I no, it gets set properly, the code behind invokes the OnStopMeasurementExecute() function exactly as the StopMeasurementCommand does, I add the code to the the initial post

Comment: @Dennis You do not need to do that in code-behind. It looks like the button is still in `IsChecked="True"` state. So my best guess is that the timer does not reset `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` correctly, but for that we need to see the view model code.

Comment: For a quick check, bind the `Content` property to this property, so you see if it changes: `Content="{Binding IsDataAcquisitionActivated}"`. If it stays `False` after the timer runs out, it confirms the issue.

Comment: Okay, the behavior is really strange. I have set a breakpoint in the `OnStartMeasurementExecute()` function right at `IsDataAcquisitionActivated=true;` and I bound the property how you suggested to see how it changes. It stays false all the time but only in the view, if i look at the property in the Visual Studio debugger it gets set correctly to true when the measurement starts. Could it be that the `IsChecked="{Binding IsDataAcquisitionActivated, Mode=TwoWay}"` attribute of the toggle button and the interaction.trigger collide somehow?

Comment: @Dennis Did you implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) interface?

Comment: Right where you wrote this I noticed the OnPropertyChanged(); was commented out for the IsDataAcquisitionActivated! It works now correctly BUT I think I remember why it was commented out (someone else worked on the project now and then, too): The StopMeasurement function seems to get fired twice now which i can see because the "Live data stopped after ..." status message gets triggered twice. But ONLY if it's done via the timer, not if i press the STOP button myself. ...... Thank you a lot for your help already by the way ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your issue is that the `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` is reset in the view model, but you do not raise a property changed notification. Therefore the bindings will not be notified of the change and hold their old value, which is `false`. This means, although the text on the button changes, it is still in *Unchecked* state, resulting in `StopMeasurementCommand` being executed.

---

> I noticed the `OnPropertyChanged();` was commented out for the `IsDataAcquisitionActivated`! [...] I remember why it was commented out [...]: The `StopMeasurement` function seems to get fired twice now which i can see because the "Live data stopped after ..." status message gets triggered twice now.

Correct. Let us review the sequence of events in this scenario to find the issue.

1. The `ToggleButton` is clicked.
2. The measurement is started, `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` is set to `true` from the `ToggleButton`.
3. A property changed notification is raised.
4. The `ToggleButton` changes its state to *Checked*.
5. The `Checked` event is raised and invokes the `StartMeasurementCommand` starting the timer.
6. The timer runs out and invokes `OnStopMeasurementExecute`. (**First time**).
7. The method sets `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` to `false`.
8. A property changed notification is raised.
9. The `ToggleButton` changes its state to *Unchecked*.
10. The `Unchecked` event is raised and invokes the `StopMeasurementCommand` (**Second time**).
11. ...and so on.

The fundamental issue is to rely on events here **while** binding the `IsChecked` state two-way. It is way easier to do one or the other, if there is no requirement against it.

In the event sequence you see that the timer invokes the `OnStopMeasurementExecute` method twice through executing it and indirectly triggering the `OnStopMeasurementExecute` command from the `ToggleButton`. If you do not call the method, but only set the `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` property instead, it will only be called once.

```
if (ts.Seconds >= MeasureTime) IsDataAcquisitionActivated = false;
```

This does not require much adaption in your code, although I would prefer an approach that does not wire events to commands, since it is harder to comprehend and track.

---

Here are two alternative approaches with explicit event to command bindings.

### 1. Unify the Commands and Handle the State There

The `ToggleButton` only cares about the `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` property to display the correct state, *Checked* or *Unchecked*. It does not have to *set the state*, so let the command handle that. Let us use a one-way binding, since the view model is the source of truth here. Then let us combine the two separate commands to one, `ToggleMeasurementCommand`.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ButtonMeasurementConnect" 
              Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Content="{Binding ButtonDataAcquisitionName}"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsDataAcquisitionActivated, Mode=OneWay}"
              Command="{Binding ToggleMeasurementCommand}"/>
```

The `ToggleMeasurementCommand` now only delegates to a the start or stop method depending on the `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` property.

```
ToggleMeasurementCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnToggleMeasurementExecute);
```

```
private void OnToggleMeasurementExecute()
{
   if (IsDataAcquisitionActivated)
      OnStartMeasurementExecute();
   else
      OnStopMeasurementExecute();
}
```

Adapt the start and stop methods to set the correct state for `IsDataAcquisitionActivated`.

```
private void OnStartMeasurementExecute()
{
   IsDataAcquisitionActivated= false;
   //... your other code.
}

private void OnStopMeasurementExecute()
{
   IsDataAcquisitionActivated= true;
   //... your other code.
}
```

The property is set once from the view model and the `ToggleButton` only updates based on the property changed notifications it gets from the view model.

**Another thought on `ToggleButton`:** You could reconsider if you *really* need a `ToggleButton`. The text states an *action* *Start* or *Stop*, not a *state* (although there is one implicitly). Consequently with the single command, you could just use a simple `Button`, no need bind any state.

### 2. Act On Property Changes

You could react to property changes. Remove the commands and leave the two-way binding.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ButtonMeasurementConnect" 
  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Content="{Binding ButtonDataAcquisitionName}"
  IsChecked="{Binding IsDataAcquisitionActivated, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ToggleButton>
```

Now the only indication when to start or stop the measurement is a change of the property `IsDataAcquisitionActivated` or in other words, when its setter is called with a changed value.

```
public bool IsDataAcquisitionActivated
{
   get => _isDataAcquisitionActivated;
   set
   {
      if (_isDataAcquisitionActivated == value)
         return;

      _isDataAcquisitionActivated= value;
      OnPropertyChanged();

      if (_isDataAcquisitionActivated)
         OnStartMeasurementExecute();
      else
         OnStopMeasurementExecute();
   }
}
```

Then of course, your timer would not call `OnStopMeasurementExecute` anymore, but only set the property, since the method will be called automatically then.

```
if (ts.Seconds >= MeasureTime) IsDataAcquisitionActivated = false;
```

Comment: @Dennis I have added a third option, that should work with your code easily. However, I would advise you to rather use a single command instead of routing events to commands.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm already busy following your advice! I can even apply it to other parts of the application where I handled similar code in the same way but it didn't stand out because there is no message in the status window!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that the function to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` was not invoked in the property bound to the `IsChecked` attribute of the toggle button.

Now that it is set the timer in the code behind resets the button correctly as pressing the Stop button does.

One downside came up with this. For some reason the method invoked by the `StopMeasurementCommand` gets fired twice in a row but that is a different issue.